# How can I listen to input as it changes while typed?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm trying to use `ngModel` to accomplish this using the following template markup:

```
<input
    [ngModel]="searchString"
    name="searchString" 
    (ngModelChange)="searchStringChange($event)"
    id="search-input"
    type="text" 
    class="form-control input-lg" 
    placeholder="Search"
>
```

Unfortunately, in my component's `searchStringChange()`, it doesn't seem to even execute it.

I'm wondering if I am doing this correctly.  I have a `searchString` and as the user types, say "C-A-T-E-R-P-I-" etc, I want to be notified of the updates.

In React I would use state to do this, but I'm not sure after reading the forms part on the tutorial how to do this.

Comment: You could switch to the reactive forms module rather than template forms. Then you can subscribe to the stream of changes made to the form values as the user types, for either a single control or the whole form, and do clever stuff like debounce it and wait for unique new values.

Comment: Works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/8ZI3HGHeFxghnFvLjHS7?p=preview. Post a complete example reproducing the problem.